# What is reverseMetadataMerge in UI Components?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

When I look at [the documentation of UI Components](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_xmldeclaration_concept.html), I notice the following:

```
<item name="reverseMetadataMerge" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

Now, most arguments are pretty self-explaining in what they do, or I already know it, but what does `reverseMetadataMerge` do?

Answer (score 12):

The setting you mention is used in `vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php`

```
 $reverseMerge = isset($componentArguments['data']['reverseMetadataMerge'])
            && $componentArguments['data']['reverseMetadataMerge'];
        $bundleComponents = $this->mergeMetadata($identifier, $bundleComponents, $reverseMerge);
```

this will merge the already defined metadata in the `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml` with some other metadata defined in the constructor of the data provider.

```
protected function mergeMetadata($identifier, array $bundleComponents, $reverseMerge = false)
{
    $dataProvider = $this->getDataProvider($identifier, $bundleComponents);
    if ($dataProvider instanceof DataProviderInterface) {
        $metadata = [
            $identifier => [
                'children' => $dataProvider->getMeta(),
            ],
        ];
        $bundleComponents = $this->mergeMetadataItem($bundleComponents, $metadata, $reverseMerge);
    }

    return $bundleComponents;
}
```

In the case of the documentation your data provider is `vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Customer/DataProvider.php` that inside the constructor has

```
 $this->meta['customer']['children'] = $this->getAttributesMeta(
        $this->eavConfig->getEntityType('customer')
    );
    $this->meta['address']['children'] = $this->getAttributesMeta(
        $this->eavConfig->getEntityType('customer_address')
    );
```

that adds some other attributes. In the case of the customer the attributes are the ones shown in blue color in the following image

[image: customer added attributes]